# What do Rheya's words really mean in the final scenes?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, solaris

In *Solaris* (2002), Chris accidentally cuts his finger in his kitchen, the wound immediately heals. Then he saw his wife Rheya in a shocking manner and asks these lines:

> Chris: Am I alive or dead?
>
> Rheya: **We don't have to think like that any more**. We're together
>   now. Everything we've done is forgiven.

How to understand Rheya's reply to Chris's question here? Where were they really? What does it mean that they don't have to worry about being alive or dead anymore?